# Try to extract paragraph using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
                    
URL = 'https://www.askgamblers.com/online-casinos/countries/uk'
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(2)
urls= []
page_links =driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='card__desc']//a[starts-with(@href, '/online')]")
for link in page_links:
    href=link.get_attribute("href")
    urls.append(href)
    #print(href)

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        review=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='review-main__show']")))
        review.click()
    except:
        pass
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")

    try:
        paragraph=soup.select_one("h2:-soup-contains('Virtual Games')").nextSibling.textContent
        print(paragraph)
    except:
        print('empty')
        pass
```

`Detail:-`

I am trying to extract these paragraph but they give me `none` when you click on `read more` then you see these whole paragraph these is the page link https://www.askgamblers.com/online-casinos/reviews/mr-play-casino these is whole paragraph I wont to extract

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Actually, detailed paragraph is visualized in the html dom and click on thereviews just go down to the page and the jab can be done by scrolling button too.The subject matter is that clicking on reviews will not work rather will create exception.
2. The big problem is to select the virtual games paragraph html nodes perfectly becase all the p nodes are in the same level thats why whatever selection it grabs the entire paragraph.So the split method generates the right output here.

**Working code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
                    
URL = 'https://www.askgamblers.com/online-casinos/countries/uk'
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(2)

urls= []
data = []
page_links =driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='card__desc']//a[starts-with(@href, '/online')]")
for link in page_links:
    href=link.get_attribute("href")
    urls.append(href)
    #print(href)

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(1)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")

    try:
        paragraph=soup.select_one('section[class="review-text richtext"]').get_text(' ',strip=True).split('Virtual Games')[1].split('Live Casino')[0]
        #print(paragraph)
    except:
        #print('empty')
        pass
    data.append({'Virtual Games':paragraph})
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Virtual Games': ' Players who enjoy video slots have a large selection to choose from here with titles from gaming suppliers like NetEnt, Microgaming and Play’n GO. The casino is home to some of the newest and popular games in the market with a range of themes to suit all. Titles include the Starburst Slot , Aloha! Cluster Pays Slot , Moon Princess Slot and Birds on a Wire Slot . When it comes to table games members will be able to enjoy some blackjack and 
roulette games including Roulette Pro and Blackjack Solo. There is also a small selection of video pokers for players who enjoy betting with cards such as Jacks or Better. In addition to that, members can pick from multiple Scratch 
card games for added entertainment. '}, {'Virtual Games': ' Bet365 Casino gives players a full range of online casino games to choose from, including a wide variety of table games, arcades, online slots, video poker and several live dealer choices. Players can find their favourite games under both the Casino and Games tab in the site’s header. Slots lovers have an immense selection of game options at their disposal. Among our favourites are Age of the Gods slot , Immortal Romance slot , to name a few. Those looking for table games will also have a massive collection of roulette, blackjack, baccarat and other casino games to choose from. In addition to this, poker lovers will also find a 
great offer that will suit their taste, including Jacks or Better, Joker Poker, and Deuces Wild. '}, {'Virtual Games': ' Players who open the casino lobby will be greeted with lots of video slots and there is plenty of variety to cater for all kinds of people. In fact, they have a game library of over 1000+ games from some of the best providers in the industry. The lobby is easy to use and players can easily find their favourite game by using the search facility and can filter the games by each individual provider too. Titles here include the Book of Dead Slot , Gonzo’s Quest Slot , Bonanza Slot , Immortal Romance Slot and Mega Moolah Slot . There are table games to enjoy here as well, especially handy for players who enjoy card and dice games. These include variations of blackjack, roulette and other traditional games. Players who like card games can try the casinos selection of video poker games and these include Jacks or Better and All Aces. There are also some ‘Other’ games available in the lobby too for anyone who is looking for something different. '}, {'Virtual Games': ' Slot lovers will find a good variety of both bonus video slots and classic fruity-style games at Trada Casino. These include titles from both Microgaming and PariPlay, including popular favourites like Immortal Romance , Avalon II , Tomb Raider , Big Bad Wolf , Rabbit in the Hat , Jurassic Park , and many more variants. Trada Casino also has an exceptional variety of bingo , keno , scratch games , and specialties from various providers. Bingo players can choose from several different gaming styles and themes with titles like Mayan Bingo, Super Bonus Bingo, and Samba Bingo. Those who love to scratch can try to win big with games like Whack a Jackpot , Slam Funk , and Turtley Awesome . Table game enthusiasts can choose from several different roulette and blackjack variants at Trada Casino, such as Classic Blackjack, Spanish Blackjack, Vegas Strip Blackjack, American 
Roulette, Premier Roulette Diamond, and French Roulette. Trada Casino’s selection of video pokers from Microgaming is comprehensive and covers practically every main variety of the game, with many offered in both single-hand and multi-hand versions. Available variants include Aces & Faces, Deuces Wild, Double Double Bonus, Louisiana Double, Tens 
or Better, Joker Poker, and Jacks or Better. '}, {'Virtual Games': " PlayFrank Casino is home to an extensive selection of slots . Players will find hit titles from Betsoft, Microgaming, NYX Interactive, Play'n Go, and NetEnt. Some 
of the most famous ones include Aliens slot , Starburst slot , Mr. Vegas slot , Foxin’ Wins Again slot , At the Movies slot , and Chimney Sweep slot . Also, the casino hosts numerous of the world’s most popular progressive slots like Mega Fortune Slot and Hall of Gods, with jackpots often in the multi-million range. In addition to its live table 
games , PlayFrank Casino provides players with a number of virtual table game favourites. These include several variants of European and French Roulette; blackjack games like Single Deck Blackjack and Double Exposure Blackjack; multiple types of Punto Banco/Baccarat; and many other favourites. Play Frank Casino’s video poker selection contains many classic and modern variants from both NetEnt and GamesOS. Among these are All American Poker, Jacks or Better, Deuces Wild, Joker Wild, Shockwave Poker, and Coliseum Poker, among others. Live Games PlayFrank Casino features an extensive live dealer room powered by Evolution Gaming. Players here can enjoy round-the-clock table game excitement in dozens of different live rooms. The game selection includes a surprising number of Live Blackjack, Live Roulette, 
and Live Baccarat variants, all dealt to professional standards and broadcast in real-time. Mobile Gaming PlayFrank 
Casino makes satisfying mobile players a key priority. The site’s HTML5 interface is designed to make it easy to play on virtually any device, from a home computer to smartphones and tablets . Players can enjoy dozens of their favourite slots and table games on the go. No app download is necessary. Support The PlayFrank Casino support team is available in English, German and Norwegian. Players via the site’s live chat facility, available from 7 AM till 23 PM. 
Also, players can reach the casino support team by email or telephone, on top of having a helpful FAQ section at their disposal, where certain previously answered questions can be found. Security and Fairness PlayFrank Casino protects players with the state-of-the-art SSL encryption. This technology is the gold standard for online safety and it is trusted by all reputable online merchants and banks. It prevents anyone from seeing sensitive data with an advanced algorithm that cannot be decoded. The games at PlayFrank Casino meet the standards of fairness required by two independent testing agencies : TST and iTech Labs . As such, players can rest assured that they will find a fair game here."}, {'Virtual Games': " PlayFrank Casino is home to an extensive selection of slots . Players will find hit titles from Betsoft, Microgaming, NYX Interactive, Play'n Go, and NetEnt. Some of the most famous ones include Aliens slot , Starburst slot , Mr. Vegas slot , Foxin’ Wins Again slot , At the Movies slot , and Chimney Sweep slot . Also, 
the casino hosts numerous of the world’s most popular progressive slots like Mega Fortune Slot and Hall of Gods, with jackpots often in the multi-million range. In addition to its live table games , PlayFrank Casino provides players with a number of virtual table game favourites. These include several variants of European and French Roulette; blackjack games like Single Deck Blackjack and Double Exposure Blackjack; multiple types of Punto Banco/Baccarat; and many other favourites. Play Frank Casino’s video poker selection contains many classic and modern variants from both 
NetEnt and GamesOS. Among these are All American Poker, Jacks or Better, Deuces Wild, Joker Wild, Shockwave Poker, and Coliseum Poker, among others. Live Games PlayFrank Casino features an extensive live dealer room powered by Evolution Gaming. Players here can enjoy round-the-clock table game excitement in dozens of different live rooms. The game selection includes a surprising number of Live Blackjack, Live Roulette, and Live Baccarat variants, all dealt to 
professional standards and broadcast in real-time. Mobile Gaming PlayFrank Casino makes satisfying mobile players a 
key priority. The site’s HTML5 interface is designed to make it easy to play on virtually any device, from a home computer to smartphones and tablets . Players can enjoy dozens of their favourite slots and table games on the go. No 
app download is necessary. Support The PlayFrank Casino support team is available in English, German and Norwegian. 
Players via the site’s live chat facility, available from 7 AM till 23 PM. Also, players can reach the casino support team by email or telephone, on top of having a helpful FAQ section at their disposal, where certain previously answered questions can be found. Security and Fairness PlayFrank Casino protects players with the state-of-the-art SSL 
encryption. This technology is the gold standard for online safety and it is trusted by all reputable online merchants and banks. It prevents anyone from seeing sensitive data with an advanced algorithm that cannot be decoded. The games at PlayFrank Casino meet the standards of fairness required by two independent testing agencies : TST and iTech Labs . As such, players can rest assured that they will find a fair game here."}, {'Virtual Games': ' Slots are a big part of the Hello! Casino game library. Players will find more than 400 different video slot titles from big names like NetEnt, NYX Gaming group, Betsoft, Leander, Thunderkick, Aristocrat, all in a simple instant-play interface. 
Among the most popular games are Steam Tower , Twin Spin , Starburst , Gonzo’s Quest , and many others. Players who 
enjoy the thrill of the tables will find several virtual card, dice, and roulette games at Hello! Casino. Among them are Multi Wheel Roulette and French Roulette, Blackjack and Pontoon, Craps, Baccarat, Sic Bo, Red Dog Progressive, 
Texas Hold’em Pro, Oasis Poker, and Caribbean Stud. Those looking for something else will find a number of scratch games and keno games in the “Lottery” section, as well as four different video poker variants under “Other” available in both single-hand and multi-hand denominations. '}, {'Virtual Games': ' As 21Prive Casino uses a number different software providers it’s no wonder that they have a rich games portfolio with over 500 games which should meet the taste of different players. Games are easily accessible and carefully categorised. However, there isn’t a search option available. Slot players can choose from a wide ranging collection, which includes classic, progressive and 3D slots. 21Prive Casino puts the effort to freshen up their selection with new and modern slots such as Lost Island slot 
. Players can also find some old classics such as Dead or Alive slot . Popular slots at 21Prive Casino are also Jack and the Beanstalk slot , Zombie Rush slot and Starburst slot . If you are more of a table games fan you will like the choice of games that 21Prive Casino have to offer. Here you can find a good selection of games that include Blackjack, Roulette, Baccarat, Craps, Pai Gow, Red Dog Progressive and many more. 21Prive Casino also have a good offer for poker players including games such as Jacks or Better, Deuces WIld, 3D Video Poker, Multihand Joker Poker and other. There is a number of other casino games too, such as fun and scratch games, ball games and virtual games. Live Games At 21Prive Casino players can also try their luck with live games. At live casino players can choose whether they want to play Roulette, Baccarat, Blackjack or Lottery. Mobile Gaming Players can also enjoy gaming on the go via 
their compatible mobile devices. They can login via their tablets or smartphones or register a new account and play 
their favourite games regardless of where they are. Available games include Starburst, Gonzos Quest, Blood Suckers and Foxin Wins. Support If you have any concern or inquiry, feel free to contact customer support at 21Prive Casino Casino. They are available to players every day during the week from 24/7 GMT . Players can contact the casino’s support team via live chat or e-mail and get assistance with their issues from professionals. Players can also get answers to some questions in the casino’s FAQ section. Security and Fairness 21Prive Casino tends to put the safety of their players first. Therefore, they use RapidSSL encryption , which is the strongest SSL encryption available on the 
market at this time. In this way, they are making sure that the players account and personal data are safe. It prevents anyone from tampering with it. As far as fairness goes, all of the casino games are tested and certified at the 
highest levels to ensure fair game-play at all times.'}, {'Virtual Games': ' As the casino is supported by the NetEnt , Microgaming , Elk Studios, NYX Interactive and Qiuckspin, some of the most popular video slots include Forbidden Throne Slot , Fairytale Legends: Hansel & Gretel Slot , Taco Brothers Slot , Big Bad Wolf Slot . Here, players may 
also find the progressive slots like Mega Moolah slot , Mega Fortune slot and Arabian Nights slot . Table game lovers can choose between different variations of the classic casino games like blackjack, roulette and baccarat. Likewise, video poker fans can also find something to suit their taste, such as Deuces Wild Double Up, Jacks or Better, Aces and Eights and Joker Wild. '}, {'Virtual Games': ' Members can join the adventure and dive into an endless ocean of exciting games, over 1200+ games to be exact. This includes the latest video slots from leading gaming providers like NetEnt, Microgaming and NextGen Gaming. To make it easier to browse members can filter the games by each individual provider. There’s actually multiple filters available to help players get to their favourite games quicker. Players can enjoy games like the Bonanza Slot, Thunderstruck 2 Slot, Immortal Romance Slot, Moon Princess Slot, Asgardian Stones Slot and Medusa Slot. There’s also a selection of table games available here so players can place their bets on games a little different. A number of different games and bet limits are also available to cater for everyone’s needs. These include Blackjack Turbo and French Roulette Pro. Video pokers can also be found here as the casino is 
home to dedicated card games section. Members can enjoy pokers like Jacks or Better, Deuces Wild and Joker Poker. '}, {'Virtual Games': ' Players can enjoy over 500 high-definition video slots from some of the biggest names in the industry like Microgaming and NetEnt . The casino regularly adds the newest games and the library features smash-hit 
titles such as Thunderstruck Slot , Starburst Slot , and Jack and the Beanstalk Slot , to mention a few. Die-hard table game lovers also have plenty to choose from. There are variants of blackjack and roulette like European Blackjack, Classic Blackjack, American Roulette, French roulette, and loads more. Video pokers are also available. Fans can 
play games like Jacks or Better, Aces & Eights, Deuces Wild, among others. Live Games Players who like the thrill of a land-based casino can enjoy live games from Evolution Gaming and other providers, including Live Blackjack, Live 
Roulette, Live Baccarat, and others. Mobile Gaming Spinland also offers a mobile casino that can be played straight 
through a mobile browser, without the need to download any additional software. Support Players who need assistance 
can enjoy 24/7 live chat with a friendly and professional support team. Questions can also be sent through email for a quick response. Security and Fairness Members can rest assured they are playing in a safe environment as the casino employs SSL encryption to protect personal and financial details. A random number generator is also utilized to ensure that all their games result in a random outcome. Furthermore, the site is closely monitored and regulated by eCogra .'}, {'Virtual Games': ' Players can enjoy loads of games here which happens to be from some of the most well 
known games in the industry. The lobby is very user friendly due to the number of filters players can use to find their favourite games. These include sorting games by their volatility levels, game provider, features, themes, number of paylines, reels and even minimum and maximum bet limits. There’s also a search engine which is a handy tool which can find any game, instantly. Players can enjoy games like the Cleopatra Slot , Wolf Gold Slot , Holmes and the Stolen Stones Slot , Reactoonz Slot and Gonzo’s Quest Slot . There’s lots of table games here too, particularly variations of blackjack and roulette. But, there are some poker games too. And, while we’re on the subject of card games players can also search for a number of video poker games as well. These include Joker Poker and Double Down Poker. '}, {'Virtual Games': ' Members can enjoy video slots here from the likes of NetEnt,\xa0Microgaming, Amatic Industries and many more well-known suppliers. Games have already been categorized from A-Z, so it helps members to go straight to the games their looking for and makes it easier to browse. There are titles ranging from the newest games to the oldest games and the most popular games. Titles include the Starburst Slot , Aloha! Cluster Pays Slot , The Phantom of the Opera Slot and Highlander Slot . In addition to slots players can enjoy a large selection of table games here starting with low-limit games to suit all budgets. These include classics like Blackjack, Roulette, Baccarat and Caribbean Stud. For those who like betting in card games players can choose from a variety of video pokers like Bonus Power Poker, Deuces Wild Poker and Double Bonus Poker. '}, {'Virtual Games': ' Members can enjoy video slots here from the likes of NetEnt,\xa0Microgaming, Amatic Industries and many more well-known suppliers. Games have already 
been categorized from A-Z, so it helps members to go straight to the games their looking for and makes it easier to 
browse. There are titles ranging from the newest games to the oldest games and the most popular games. Titles include the Starburst Slot , Aloha! Cluster Pays Slot , The Phantom of the Opera Slot and Highlander Slot . In addition to slots players can enjoy a large selection of table games here starting with low-limit games to suit all budgets. These include classics like Blackjack, Roulette, Baccarat and Caribbean Stud. For those who like betting in card games players can choose from a variety of video pokers like Bonus Power Poker, Deuces Wild Poker and Double Bonus Poker. '}, {'Virtual Games': ' 21 Casino’s biggest selection of games are its slots . Players will find a highly diverse collection, from simple games to innovative five-reel bonus video slots. Some of the most popular releases include Starburst , Magicious , Medusa II Slot , Merlin’s Millions , Miss Midas Slot , Aliens , Dragon Island , and Mega Fortune . In addition to live table games , 21 Casino features a diverse library of card, dice, and roulette games for all kinds of players. These include Caribbean Stud Poker, Casino Hold’em, Craps, Red Dog, Sharp Shooter, Six Shooter, 
and numerous Blackjack and Roulette variants. Video poker players at 21 Casino have an abundance of single-hand and 
multi-hand variants to choose from. It contains the full line of NetEnt video pokers (Jacks or Better, Deuces Wild, 
Joker Wild, and All American Poker), as well as the even more diverse Betsoft video pokers with paytables like Deuces and Jokers, Double Bonus Poker, and Double Jackpot Poker. 21 Casino is also home to a variety of instant win games . These include multiple variants of Keno, unique games like Predictor, and scratchers like Max Win Scratch and Lucky Double. Live Games The live casino at 21 Casino is more diverse than most. Players can enjoy real-time gaming broadcast from a professional casino studio with 5 different games to choose from: Live Baccarat, Live Blackjack, Live 
Roulette, Live Keno, and Live Lottery. All of the games are dealt to professional standards and have interactive features for a more social gaming experience. Mobile Gaming Many of the games at 21 Casino can be enjoyed on the go thanks to its HTML5-compatible mobile platform. It works with almost all modern smartphones and tabl e ts, including iOS and Android devices . Players don’t have to worry about any downloads and can count on a virtually identical gaming experience. Support 21 Casino strives to provide players with support as efficiently as possible. The site’s live 
chat function is always just a click away and open 24/7 , connecting players with representatives in minutes or less in most cases. The “Help” page states that representatives are available 24/7, but we have found that this is not always the case. In the event that no one is online, players may send the casino an email and wait until the next business day for a reply instead. Additionally, support is available both in English and Dutch. Security and Fairness All sensitive areas of the 21 Casino website are encrypted with state-of-the-art technology from GlobalSign , a leading security firm. This protocol obscures private information like financial data and passwords, making it virtually 
impossible for anyone to compromise player accounts. All of the games used at 21 Casino have been thoroughly audited by a trusted independent agency, such as TST or iTech Labs .'}, {'Virtual Games': ' Being a Microgaming casino , it provides players with an excellent selection of slot games to suit every kind of preference, with favorites like Avalon II , Immortal Romance , Thunderstruck II , Elementals , Break da Bank , Playboy , Money Mad Monkey , Starlight 
Kiss and so much more. However, being a new comer to online gaming market, Conquer Casino’s list of slot games is not yet comprehensive with its 180+ games, out of which, 13 are jackpot games. Nevertheless, these should accommodate 
most demands for choice of games. Table games too are still limited in number, with only 15 variance of Roulette, Blackjack and Baccarat available, the live game versions included, but players can expect more additions in due time. 
Video Poker lovers will have to miss out at Conquer Casino as none is currently available, similarly for special games fans too, but scratch cards fans, on the other hand, are well catered for with over 30 games to choose from. Live Games Live games are also available for players and live dealers run the following games: Multi Player Baccarat , Live Baccarat , Live Blackjack , Multi Player Roulette and Live Roulette . Mobile Gaming Users of iOS and Android mobile units can access the casino via an internet connection and there are currently 20 games available for play, such as Avalon, Break da Bank, Burning Desire, Cashapillar, Hitman, Mermaid Millions, Starlight Kiss, Thunderstruck II and Tomb Raider, to name a few. As more and more become mobile players in due time, the number of games available for mobile gaming would increase in tandem. Support Customer support services is available via live chat between 7 AM and 11 PM (GMT). Alternatively, players can email the support and get a prompt response. Security and Fairness Being 
licensed and regulated in Malta under some of the strictest world’s gambling legislation, all personal information, 
account details and transactions of players are treated with strictest confidence and are not disclosed to any third party. The Random Number Generator (RNG) is audited and tested by Gaming Associates to ensure fairness of the games at all times.'}, {'Virtual Games': " The video slot section is powered by Amatic Industries, and includes video slots like Lucky Zodiac slot , Wild Shark slot , Wolf Moon slot and numerous others. Players looking to try their hand 
at table games can go for blackjack and a variety of live table games. The video poker offer includes different video poker variants like Deuces Wild, Fruit Poker, Jacks or Better, Joker Card, Multi Win and Multi Win Triple. Live Games The casino has a live casino where players can engage in live gambling . The live casino offer includes various 
live table games, such as different types of live roulette, live blackjack and live punto banco, which is a type of 
live baccarat. All tables are hosted by Netent live and Evolution Gaming. Mobile Gaming Since CasinoCasino is a mobile casino , players can play the casino's video slots and other online casino games on their mobile devices. Support Players who need to contact the customer support team can do so via email, phone, online contact phone or live chat , which is open from 08:00 to 01:00 (CET) . Alternatively, these is a FAQ section where players can find answers to various previously asked questions. Security and Fairness The games found in the casino's offer implement Random Number Generators which ensure the outcome is always unbiased."}, {'Virtual Games': ' Players at Barbados Casino have 
plenty of online slots and table games to choose from. Naturally, their video slots selection is the biggest and is 
powered by NetEnt , Microgaming , Elk Studios, with popular titles like Foxin’ Wins slot , Copy Cats slot , Taco Brothers slot and EmotiCoins slot . Table games enthusiasts can pick between different variations of the classic casino games of blackjack, roulette and baccarat. These alternatives include Roulette Royal, European Roulette, Baccarat Squeeze, Blackjack Solo and Blackjack Classic. Video poker fans can also find games that suit their taste. These contain Jacks or Better, Deuces Wild, Joker Poker, Royal Poker and Poker King. Additionally, the casino also offers a number of keno and scratch card games. '}, {'Virtual Games': " The casino lobby boasts hundreds of the industry's best video slots from some of the most talked about providers in the market like NetEnt , Microgaming and Play’n GO . Players can easily search for their favourite games which will help find them quicker but other than that other filters here are limited. Players will have to browse the lobby until they find what they want to play. Titles include the Book of Dead Slot , Bonanza Slot , Aloha! Cluster Pays Slot , Thunderstruck 2 Slot and Starburst Slot . Of course, 
there are table games here as well for anyone looking to play something different to slots. These include popular versions of blackjack and roulette. Players who prefer card games can try their luck with the video poker games like Jacks or Better and Joker Poker. The casino lobby is also home to some other casino games like scratch cards. "}, {'Virtual Games': ' SlotsMagic is
```

... so on